# Dynamically invoking a constructor in PHP with variable number of arguments

Tags: php, constructor, parameter-passing, instantiation

I need to instantiate an object of a specific class type, but dynamically and with variable number of arguments. Essentially, I want a framework method that is similar to `call_user_func_array()` :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

But I want the arguments to be for a constructor, not a function.

So, instead of doing this:

```
$object = new MyClass(a, b, c);
```

...I want to be doing this:

```
$object = call_constructor_array('MyClass', array(a, b, c));
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: @Jonnix It would be nice if it works on version 5.* (which I am mostly interested in), but if it is doable in later versions, feel free to reply.

Comment: 5.6+ (as you'll see on the dupe) can be done with `new MyClass(...$yourArray)`.

Comment: Yep. I think that question is pretty much what I was looking for, just using terminology I would never use to ask the question... Thanks. :)